# iTunes limitations( with respect to filetypes )?

Tags: windows-7, itunes, file-management, media

What filetypes does iTunes *not* recognize ? I have a bunch of flac files, some avi videos, and none of them seem to be in my iTunes library. Nothing happens when I import them ( via Drag & Drop, importing them via File -> Add files). 
Is there any way for iTunes to manage them ?

I really want to use a single app for all my media management, and it was WMP prior to purchasing my iPhone, and now with the iPhone, but with these limitations, it seems I will have to mix and match both, which I want to avoid. Any options ?

Comment: it definitely does *not* support FLAC unfortunately.  This drives me bananas as I use FLAC to archive all of my cds.  There is a utility out there that adds it but I can't remember the name right now :/

Comment: @calavera I dumped iTunes & now I use foobar 2000. Launch iTunes when I want to sync.. which is rare since most of my important data -  Contacts / Notes / e-mails is on the proverbial cloud.

Comment: I would love to dump iTunes for foobar but most of my machines are OS X... I haven't been able to find anything like foobar on the Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching a bit I found [this on Apple's KB](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2729#3) -

> What video content works with iTunes
>   and iPod? iTunes:
>
> Video content purchased from the
>   iTunes Store. QuickTime and MPEG-4
>   movie files that end in ".mov",
>   ".m4v", or ".mp4" and are playable in
>   QuickTime Player. Video podcasts.

*Sigh*.

Answer (score 3):

I've had a look through the Apple Support pages, but can't find any answer to that question. The [Wikipedia entry for iTunes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Itunes) says that iTunes can "read, write and convert between MP3, AIFF, WAV, MPEG-4, AAC and Apple Lossless." In addition it states that it can also play back any audio files that Quicktime can handle.

From the Apple Support pages, the list of supported audio and video formats for Quicktime (albeit on OSX 10.6/Snow Leopard) [is available here](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3775). It lists the supported audio formats as:

- iTunes Audio (.m4a, .m4b, .m4p)
- MP3
- Core Audio (.caf)
- AIFF
- AU
- SD2
- WAV
- SND
- AMR

The following video formats are supported (although do also check the Video Codecs listed on the [apple support page](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3775)):

- QuickTime Movie (.mov)
- MPEG-4 (.mp4, .m4v)
- MPEG-1
- 3GPP
- 3GPP2
- AVI
- DV

Comment: So there's no way for iTunes to manage my avi files ? :-(

Comment: Sorry missed the bit about avi's - it was in the link I gave to the Apple support page, but I'll update my answer.